# Is the Kolat Towers map properly drawn?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, battle-map, waterdeep-dragon-heist

In *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*, players can access a zone known as [Kolat Towers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/winter-wizardry#KolatTowers). The map (on p. 151) is drawn strangely though.

[image: Kolat Towers map, level 1 and 2]

It seems like the 2nd floor is not aligned with the 1st floor. Not very usual, I think. I'm building the map in 3D for my Halloween session later this week, and I'm unsure if I should build something like this

[image: Kolat Towers map with levels overlaid]

(notice how the stairs position on K4, misaligned with the stairs position in K6). The other option would be to redraw the map so the walls and stairs align.

Is this map drawn correctly, and the walls are unaligned (therefore I just need to slightly reconfigure some stairs between K4 and K6), or did designers just brainfart half-way through floors, and it would be better to remake the map?

*To clarify, it's perfectly possible that the castle has floors with different orientations and the stairs are just 5ft to the side, a small mistake. I'm just confirming that I'm not doing something wrong that will later screw me when I'm half-way through my model.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think so, yeah. However, on the opposite side of the wall, the floor of K7 has no support between K3 and K4

Comment: @HeyICanChan Mostly that 1) buildings (or castles) don't usually have walls with different orientations in different floors, and that 2) the stairs are in different places with this configuration

Comment: Could you clarify about the stairs? They seem aligned to me.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I've remade the image. The stairs in K4 are a bit (not too much, but a bit) sideways

Comment: I think the stairs on each floor are aligned to the nearest 5-foot square grid on that floor for gameplay convenience, at the cost of having them not align perfectly with each other.

Comment: With regard to the outer walls, maybe something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6vIW.png The stairs can start and end unaligned even if they are spiral, they just spiral wonkily.

Comment: @jgn Great pic, I'll incorporate it in the answer

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I think the structure makes a lot more sense if you think about a possible roof, pillars, buttresses, external detailing, etc, which wouldn't make it onto an interior map. Be sure to update the answer with pics of your finished model, it will be a valuable example of how you solved these problems! (plus I want to see)

Comment: @jgn I'm not sure I'll make it justice, friend, but I'll certainly try

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## It's a crooked building.

The [City of Splendors box set](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/City_of_Splendors_(boxed_set)) depicts the towers, as [illustro](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/36850/illustro) pointed out in a comment:

[image: City of Splendors box set - Wizards' Kolat Towers and Guard Post, southwestern view]

Following [Ryan Thompson](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/40516/ryan-thompson)'s idea, I searched for the Kolat Towers' lore. According to the [Forgotten Realms wiki entry](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Kolat_Towers):

> The building known as Kolat Towers started out as an old stone manor and a pair of sturdy cottages. Before 1368 DR, the wizard brothers, Alcedor and Duhlark Kolat, bought the buildings and, much to the chagrin of the local building guilds, stitched the building together using spells such as *wall of stone* and *stone shape*.

So having misaligned walls actually falls in-line with the way they were created, in sections, haphazardly. [jgn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/59609/jgn) posted a great 3D rendering of the layout.

[image: Kolat Towers - jgn's 3D rendering]

There is a small misalignment between some stairs, which can either be a small drawing mistake, or a spiral staircase with a tilted support, like this.

[image: spiral staircase]

Interesting concept, if made on purpose. This is the cardboard model map I ended up with.

[image: Kolat Towers - cardboard model]

Comment: The City of Splendors box set from 2e included an a1 size photo poster of a model TSR made of part of Waterdeep that included Kolat Tower

Comment: A side view of the mode in the map was also featured on the back of the box

Comment: If you search eBay for "City of Splendors box set" and look at the pictures of the first 3-4 entries you can see a birds eye view on one of the pictures, and side views in a number of the others of Kolat Towers

Comment: @illustro Maybe I'm not finding the right photos, but those seem to have a castle-like terrace on the 2nd floor. Maybe it is a different version of the building, or a different (albeit similar) building?

Comment: This is of the same box set of Amazon, but picture 5 has the best side view of Kolat Towers from the poster map. https://www.amazon.com/Splendors-FORGOTTEN-REALMS-CAMPAIGN-EXPANSION/dp/1560768681#immersive-view_1572883165257

Comment: Picture 7 in that set shows two more views of the tower, one immersed in its surroundings and another (on the bottom corner of the box) showing yet another standalone view of the tower

Comment: I compared the maps from that box set and WDH when I ran it, and Kolat towers is located in the same spot on both maps. Also the lore presented in the description of the towers is the same as the lore presented on the FR Wiki that you found

Comment: @illustro Correct, I misinterpreted one of the pictures

Comment: Great work on the cardboard model, it looks a lot more plausible than the box art!